# Realized Option Return as a Function of Moneyness at Expiration

Tags: option-pricing

Main question: How does realized option return vary as a function of moneyness at expiration?

Alternatively, if you have a crystal ball and see the exact price of a stock at some future date, what single option can you buy (Call or Put; no spreads, etc.) to maximize your return?

Intuitively, buying a deep in the money option will have lower return than the next less in the money option.  On the other hand, as you go farther out of the money, at a certain point your strike goes past the expiration price and your return drops to 0 (or -100%).  Clearly, the best return is somewhere in the middle, but what does that curve look like?

Since the answer will depend on the implied volatility, let's assume constant implied volatility (if there's a common assumption for volatility smile/smirk, I'm interested in the answer under that assumption as well).

Comment: Gamma?..........

Comment: I don't think so.  Gamma is highest at the money, so if it followed Gamma, you'd always realize the highest return on ATM options, which doesn't intuitively make sense.

Comment: If you have a directional view you buy put/calls, which are long gamma.
Yourself say "clearly the best return is in the middle", that is the moment where the temporal value is maximum, i.e. high gamma. It's through delta that you make money on directional view, therefore gamma is telling you how you accrue new delta. Finally, it is wrong to say that deep in the money will have lower return -->  the larger the delta in absolute terms, the higher the sensitivity to spot movements, therefore the higher the expected returns.

Comment: I think what you're saying makes sense for buying a set NUMBER of options.  My question is about buying a set DOLLAR AMOUNT of options.  Deep ITM options do indeed have the highest delta and so in absolute terms gain the most, but not as a percentage of the option price.  For example, 7/19 SPY call 297.5 has delta 0.8465 and costs 2.82. For 302.5 strike, delta=0.217 and C=0.37.  If SPY moves up $1, C302.5 gains 0.217/0.37=59% (more bc gamma) and C297.5 gains 0.8465/2.82=30%.

Comment: Your question is about realzied return which is the realization of expected ones. But before trading you need to take into consideration expectations. However, if you have the crystal ball for predicting future prices then you buy vanilla European call/put options, with a strike that maximizes the EXPECTED payoff. That it, you are long gamma as I said time ago